# Can I have some feedback with rspec when writing controllers specs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, rspec, rspec2

I was wondering if i could have some feedbacks with the controller spec bellow. In fact i'm new when writing specs and controller's spec are way different from model's spec ! So i'm wondering if i may not go in the wrong direction...

subjects_controller.rb

```
def show
  @subject = Subject.find(params[:id])

  if @subject.trusted?(current_user)
    @messages = @subject.messages
  else
    @messages = @subject.messages.public
    @messages = @messages + @subject.messages.where(:user_ids => current_user.id)
    @messages.uniq!
  end

  # sort the list
  @messages = @messages.sort_by(&:created_at).reverse

  if !@subject.company.id == current_user.company.id
    redirect_to(subjects_path, :notice => "Invalid subject")
  end
end
```

subjects_controller_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe SubjectsController do  
  before(:each) do
    @subject = mock_model(Subject)
  end

  context "for signed users" do
    before(:each) do
      @current_user = sign_in Factory(:user)
    end

    context "GET #show" do
      before(:each) do
        Subject.stub!(:find, @subject).and_return(@subject)
      end

      context "when current_user is trusted" do
        before(:each) do
          messages = []
          company = mock_model(Company)

          @subject.should_receive(:trusted?).and_return(true)
          @subject.should_receive(:messages).and_return(messages)
          @subject.should_receive(:company).and_return(company)
        end

        it "should render success" do
          get :show, :id => @subject
          response.should be_success
        end
      end

      context "when current_user is not trusted" do
        before(:each) do
          messages = []
          company = mock_model(Company)

          @subject.should_receive(:trusted?).and_return(false)
          @subject.should_receive(:messages).and_return(messages)
          messages.should_receive(:public).and_return(messages)
          @subject.should_receive(:messages).and_return(messages)
          messages.should_receive(:where).and_return(messages)
          @subject.should_receive(:company).and_return(company)
        end

        it "should render success" do
          get :show, :id => @subject
          response.should be_success
        end
      end

      context "when subject's company is not equal to current_user's company" do
        # I have no idea of how to implement ==
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Factories.rb

```
Factory.define :user do |u|
  u.first_name 'Test User'                          #
  u.username 'Test User'                            #
  u.surname 'TheTest'                               #
  u.email 'foo@foobar.com'                          #
  u.password 'please'                               #
  u.confirmed_at Time.now                           #
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell you're on the right path. The basic idea is to completely isolate your controller code from model and view in these tests. You appear to be doing that--stubbing and mocking model interaction.

Comment: Thx for your answer, someone else for more feedback ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't write RSpec controller specs at all. Use Cucumber stories instead. Much easier, and you get better coverage.